# Invoking multiple methods with a for loop?

Tags: java

I am required to invoke the methods getMonthIf and getMonthSwitch alternately with a "for loop" but i am unsure of how to do this.

I am assuming I need to write a loop that produces the numbers 1 through 6 (paymentNumber), and each time an increment is produced, it will invoke both methods.

The end result needs to be a table with paymentNumber (1-6) on one column and the months July - December on the column next to it. I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

```js
public class For2 {
  
  public static void main (String [] args) {
   
    

   
   printTable(6);
  
 
  }
  public static void printTable (int paymentNumber) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= paymentNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) getMonthSwitch(paymentNumber);
    else getMonthIf(paymentNumber);
     }
     
  }
    
    
  public static String getMonthIf ( int paymentNumber ) {
    if (paymentNumber  ==  1 ) 
      return "July" ;
    else if (paymentNumber == 3 )
      return "September" ;
    else if (paymentNumber == 5) 
      return "November" ;
    else  return  "Invalid Payment Number" ;
    
  }
  
  public static String getMonthSwitch ( int paymentNumber ) {
    switch (paymentNumber) { 
      case 2 : return "August";
      case 4 : return "October";
      case 6 : return "December";
      default: return "Invalid Payment Number";
    }
    
  }
  
  }
```

Comment: You should not pass the paymentNumber but i in the parameter: getMonthSwitch(i) and getMonthIf(i)

Comment: YES! it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= paymentNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        getMonthSwitch(paymentNumber);
    else
        getMonthIf(paymentNumber);
}
```

The operator `%` returns the difference after dividing, which will be 0 if `i` is divisible by 2.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I have made your edits to my code, it compiled but when I try to invoke printTable, nothing happens. I have edited the snippet and posted it above, if you could take a look, it would be awesome!

Comment: `getMonthIf` and `getMonthSwitch` return Strings, which you need to print if you want to see them. Use `System.out.println(getMonthSwitch(paymentNumber));` to see the result on the terminal.